# Reverse an ArrayList in Java, 4 elements at a time

Tags: java, list, arraylist, reverse, reorderlist

I have an ArrayList of 20 Integers which actually represents 5 sets of 4 numbers as follows:

```
1 5 9  13 17
2 6 10 14 18
3 7 11 15 19
4 8 12 16 20
```

I want to flip it so it looks like this:

```
4 8 12 16 20
3 7 11 15 19
2 6 10 14 18
1 5 9  13 17
```

I have seen other answers about how to reverse an entire list, but how would I go about traversing this List of 20, reversing the first 4, then the next 4, etc? I can't quite wrap my head around the maths that I'd need to do to accomplish it.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Are the `List`s horizontally running or vertically running? Is this a `List<List<Integer>>`?

Comment: @ifly6 It is running vertically, the numbers given in the first example represent the position of the elements in the list and then where I want them to be flipped to in the second example. It is not a list of lists, just one single list.

Comment: Split it into a list of lists, with each sub-list having 4 indices. Loop through them and reverse each sub-list.

Comment: @Mark Currently I have hard coded the flip (
List<Integer> original= getList();
        List<Integer> flipped= new ArrayList<>();
        flipped.add(original.get(3));
        flipped.add(original.get(2));
        flipped.add(original.get(1));
        flipped.add(original.get(0));
        flipped.add(original.get(7));
        flipped.add(original.get(6));
etc...

I have also considered how to handle it using a for loop but couldn't get my head around how to setup a counter or iterator to handle this behaviour.

Comment: @ifly6 Ah, good idea, very simple solution too that I was overlooking. I can then combine them into a single list again.

Comment: Edit your code into the original post.

Comment: Never put more infos into comments; update your question instead! And for the next time: please spend some time in the help center to better understand how to ask reasonable questions. Just dropping requirements is n't enough!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pseudo-code):

```
List list

int nbrElements = list.size() / 4 // number of elements, each containing 4 numbers

int index1 = 0
int index2 = nbrElements-1

while index1 < index2
    for i in {0,1,2,3} // for each number in element
        switch(index1*4+i, index2*4+i) // define a method to switch numbers
    index1++
    index2--
```

Comment: What if `list.size() % 4 != 0`?

Comment: Good point. @James is the size of the list always divisible by 4? If not, how would you sort them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic

```
     List<Integer> al= Arrays.asList(1, 5, 9,  13, 17,
            2, 6, 10, 14, 18,
            3, 7, 11, 15, 19,
            4, 8, 12, 16, 20);

    int setSize=5,listSize=al.size();
    for(int i=listSize-setSize;i>=0;i-=setSize){
        //Instead of printing you can add the sublist to a new list
        System.out.println(al.subList(i, i+setSize));
    }
```

It produces following output

```
[4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
[3, 7, 11, 15, 19]
[2, 6, 10, 14, 18]
[1, 5, 9, 13, 17]
```